# Where can I set and retrieve the environment variables used by icCube?

Tags: iccube

Within icCube there is reference to several variables, like $install, ${EXAMPLE} etcetera.

Where can I retrieve the values for these variables, and where can I set these?

Is it also possible for me to introduce new variables?

Comment: What do you mean by "wihtin icCube" ?

Comment: for example, in the demo schema Sales, you find the variable ${EXAMPLE} in Data Integration > Data Sources > files > Directory: ${EXAMPLE}/salesdemo/data

Comment: schema files do not support such variables; this $example stuff is for demo purpose only.